# Meaning of 'Have you ever been a student at XX university'?

Tags: american-english

I am required to fill in a form. One of the questions is 'Have you ever been a student at AAA university?' I am currently enrolled at AAA university but before this enrollment I wasn't a student of this university.
So how to answer this question?

Thanks

Comment: The title mentioned XX University, but the question is about AAA University. How many of these oddly named universities can a person study at?

Comment: @Michael Harvey: XX just means it could be anything. Might be different in America. I am trying my best to catch up with English speaking country's culture.

Comment: I think Michael was making a joke, but I have noticed a tendency on the forum for people to use placeholders like "XXX". I don't think it helps make the question more clear. It is better to be specific, unless there is a particular reason (such as privacy) to hide the name of something behind a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Have you ever..." is asking about any time up to and including now.

So if you are currently a student there, then *Yes, you have been a student at AAA university*.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @RaymondQin: Don't forget to accept an answer if you are happy with it. You're not likely to get one that gives you more than this. At least, not that give you any more that's relevant to your question.

Comment: @SamBC: Thanks for your reminder. This is my very first time to post a question though I have used Stack Overflow for hundreds of thousands times.